# WebClient.DownloadFileAsync - Download files one at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webclient, download

I am using the code below to download multiple attachments from a TFS server:

```
foreach (Attachment a in wi.Attachments)
{    
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Credentials = (ICredentials)netCred;
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(a.Uri, "C:\\" + a.Name);
}
```

I would like to download multiple files using DownloadFileAsync, but I want them to be downloaded one by one.

One may ask "Why don't you just use the synchronous DownloadFile method?" Its because:

1. I want to make use of the events provided by DownloadFileAsync.
2. I don't want to make multiple instances of the Webclient to avoid flooding the server.

This is the solution that I thought of:

```
foreach (Attachment a in wi.Attachments)
{        
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.Credentials = (ICredentials)netCred;
    wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(a.Uri, "C:\\" + a.Name);
    while (wc.IsBusy)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

However, there are a couple of problems with this approach:

1. The Thread.Sleep() is locking up my Form. I still need to make my own Thread or use BackgroundWorker. (I would like to avoid this as much as possible)
2. The DownloadFileCompleted event is being triggered after *ALL* files has been downloaded. I don't know if this is a side-effect of using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

Is there a better approach to download files one at a time using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync?

Thanks!

Comment: btw, you could use `System.IO.Path.Combinte("C:", a.Name");`

Comment: I'm trying but some answers are just plainly not acceptable.

Comment: You can fix the thread blocking problem by doing this: `while(wc.IsBusy) { }`. This way, as long as the `wc.IsBusy` is `true` the execution will be "stuck" in the empty "do nothing" braces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To simplify the task you can create separated attachment list:

```
list = new List<Attachment>(wi.Attachments);
```

where **list** is private field with type **List<Attachment>**.
After this you should configure WebClient and start downloading of first file:

```
if (list.Count > 0) {
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.Credentials = (ICredentials)netCred;
   wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadFileCompleted);
   wc.DownloadFileAsync(list[0].Uri, @"C:\" + list[0].Name);
}
```

Your DownloadFileComplete handler should check if not all files already downloaded and call  DownloadFileAsync again:

```
void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) {
   // ... do something useful 
   list.RemoveAt(0);
   if (list.Count > 0)
      wc.DownloadFileAsync(list[0].Uri, @"C:\" + list[0].Name);
}
```

This code is not optimized solution. This is just idea.

Comment: DON'T FORGET to use `wc.Dispose()` in the same scope after you get the response.

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of sounding like an idiot, this worked for me:

```
Console.WriteLine("Downloading...");
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(file.Value), filePath);
while (client.IsBusy)
{
    // run some stuff like checking download progress etc
}
Console.WriteLine("Done. {0}", filePath);
```

Where `client` is an instance of a `WebClient` object.

Comment: Works pretty well (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I think that should use Queue

Comment: I actually agree RE using Queue, but as Harshal said you should further explain what you're saying.