# Error in VB.net when I'm doing Auto Update

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing an auto-update program and I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type enter System.NotSupportedException
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: WebClient does not support concurrent I/O
>   operations.

Code:

```
Public Sub getUpdate()
    If System.IO.File.Exists(tool) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(tool)
        wClinet.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hqkne9iz2p6rr86/AABT-iipKShPynlasYK6VVSGa?dl=1"), directorypath + ("\KingdomGaming.exe"))
        Timer1.Start()
    Else
        System.IO.File.Delete(tool)
        wClinet.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hqkne9iz2p6rr86/AABT-iipKShPynlasYK6VVSGa?dl=1"), directorypath + ("\KingdomGaming.exe"))
        Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to download multiple files at the same time using one instance of `WebClient`? If so, `WebClient` doesn't support that. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765109/4934172).

Comment: nope **I'm not**. I'm using just this.

Comment: In this case, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50357366/edit) your question and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  that shows the life cycle of your `wClinet` variable and tell us exactly which line causes this exception. Also, if `Timer1` uses `wClinet` in any way, include that as well.