# HttpWebResponse multiple file download

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-2.0

I use this code to download a file from a url.

```
Stream stm = myHttpResponse.GetResponseStream();
byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
Stream fs = new FileStream("c:\\file1.txt", FileMode.Append , FileAccess.Write);
int r = 0;

while((r = stm.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length)) > 0)
{
    fs.Write(buff, 0, r);
}
```

If I want to download 20 files (from different urls) simultaneously it's possible to do it with less than 20 threads?

Edit

HttpWebResponse hasn't async method. I was hoping some example with BeginRead/BeginWrite of streams. I think they dont consume threads from Threadpool

Comment: Did you refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276158/infinite-loop-while-downloading-multiple-files-with-webclient/15276809#15276809 ? Both the question and Eric's suggestion would help you to choose the right way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Task Parallel Library` (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) for that. And set the [`Degree of Parallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx). On your scenario. Set it to 19.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible to have 20 **simultaneous** download streams in less than 20 threads. You could use a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and limit thread's count where, but that is not simultaneous IMO.
Anyway you are better to use the WebClient class and its [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync.aspx) method.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.DownloadFileAsync(uriString,fileName);
```