# How can I download multiple files with WebClient in C#?

Tags: c#, webclient

I can't seem to figure out how to download multiple files using DownloadFileAsync. How can I input a list as a URI?

My current code for a single download looks like this:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)");
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);

        // Starts the download
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(chosenVersion), tbFolder.Text + chosenVersionFileName);
```

'chosenVersion' is just a link, say example.com/some.jpeg.

I just want to get all the downloads bundled into one progress bar while downloading at the same time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992553/how-do-i-async-download-multiple-files-using-webclient-but-one-at-a-time/6992743#6992743 http://stackoverflow.com/a/2042428/342740

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to get all the downloads bundled into one progress bar while downloading at the same time.

An instance of WebClient can handle just one download at a time.  You can modify the approach given in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6992743/141172

to download multiple files in parallel by replacing the queue with a construct such as a `List<string>` and using [Parallel.Foreach()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to process the list concurrently.